# Resize canvas inside a jquery-ui dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, canvas

I have a jquery-ui dialog which contains a canvas, and a chessboard is drawn onto the canvas like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js></script>
<script>
$(function) {
    $("#chessboard").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        modal: false
    }

    function drawboard() {
        ctxt = document.getElementByID("chessboard").getContext("2d");

        // draw the board into the context
        ...
    }

    drawboard();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="chessboard" width="400" height="400" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

The board fills up the entire dialog, but I was pleasently surprised when I discovered that the chessboard can be resized together with the dialog. Then I tried the following in order to arrange e.g. a game notation together with the board into the dialog:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js></script>
<script>
$(function) {
    $("#chessboard-container").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        modal: false
    }

    function drawboard() {
        ctxt = document.getElementByID("chessboard").getContext("2d");

        // draw the board into the context
        ...
    }

    drawboard();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="chessboard-container">
        <canvas id="chessboard" width="400" height="400" />
        <div id="notation"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now the board is still rendered onto the canvas, but it cannot be resized with the dialog.

Is it possible to resize the chessboard-container element together with the canas?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want to bind to the "resize" event and then re-draw your chess board during that event.

add a

```
resize: function(event, ui) { drawChessBoard() }
```

to your initialization code